# Finding and replacing Google Search div's innerHTML using Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a Chrome Extension that scans through some Google Search Results and replaces the div's innerHTML (or innerText) with a string if the div's original innerHTML contains a particular word or phrase.

Whenever I try to get the divs with class "g" and try to use the value to check innerHTML and other properties associated with the div in my replaceDivs function, I always find that the variable "divs" is empty. Upon reading other Stackoverflow posts, I found out that I had to add an event listener, which I did in the document ready function. But despite adding an event listener to look for inserted nodes, I still found that the "divs" variable in my code doesn't contain anything.

While debugging the content.js file, I found that the "divs" variable is empty until after the whole page loads, so I tried to use "run_at": "document_end" in the manifest.json file. But this also didn't solve the problem since the "divs" variable was still empty when I was debugging.

I received a message like this:
[image]

My content.js file:

```
//Replaces divs inner text with a message if a particular substring is found. 
function replaceDivs() {
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("g");
    console.log(divs);
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
        var string = divs[i].innerText;
        var substr = "substring to search for";
        if (string.indexOf(substr) > -1) {
            divs[i].innerText = "This is hidden for your safety!"
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("test");
    document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', replaceDivs());
});
```

My manifest.json file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Replace Text",
    "version": "1.0", 

    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "content_scripts": [ {
        "js": [ "jquery-1.12.3.js", "content.js" ],
        "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    } ]
}
```

So my final question: How do I fix this problem so that I can use the array of divs in the Google search result page to find and replace text?

Any help would be thoroughly appreciated!

Comment: Is your replaceDivs() function getting called once?

Comment: Yes, it is getting called exactly once.

Comment: Ok..these divs added dynamically. after document.ready(). right?

Comment: You mean the Google Search results? I thought they would already be added since I specified "run_at": "document_end"?

Comment: typographic error in addEventListener call. dont put parentheses in function called.

Comment: @ZigMandel That did the trick! Thanks so much!

Comment: @ZigMandel, The function replaceDivs is executed multiple times though? Is there a way to prevent this?